# How to define new signature in sml

Tags: types, sml, smlnj, type-declaration

I am trying to extend the existing int library to a new library called "bigint". I am keeping the type of the datatype bigint as int list. Basically, I want a function (lets call it getbigint)which accepts any int and store each of its digits in a separate cell of int list and then return this int list. So if I enter:

```
getbigint 9
```

it should give me:

```
val it =[9]:bigint
```

How can I achieve this? For the time being, I assume that input to this function is single digit int only. Here is what I have done till now:

```
signature BigInt =
    sig
        type bigint = int list
        val getbigint: int -> bigint
    end;

structure struct_bigint : BigInt = 
    struct
        fun getbigint (i:int) = 
            let
              val h = [i]:bigint
            in h
            end
    end
(*val j = getbigint 9;*)
```

which is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signature implements nothing. It describes what a structure looks like to the outside world. Think of it as a specification. A structure that matches it must provide implementations of the elements in the signature. Note that when you run your code you get the following error:

```
Error: unmatched type specification: bigint
```

SML detects that you have something in a signature that isn't matched by a corresponding implementation in the structure.

A minimal fix would simply be to add the line

```
type bigint = int list
```

in the structure definition before the implementation of `fun getbigint`. This would allow the line

```
val j = struct_bigint.getbigint 9;
```

to work. But -- it might seem a bit silly to have the line

```
type bigint = int list
```

twice -- once in the signature and once in the structure. And, in some ways, it *is* silly.

Implementation details don't really belong in the signature. It would make more sense to just have `type bigint` in the *signature* and the implementation in terms of `int list` in the *structure*. This would allow you to later on change your mind about implementation (say you want to use arrays rather than lists) in such a way that code which uses the structure is completely unaffected. Something like:

```
signature BIGINT =
    sig
        type bigint
        val getbigint: int -> bigint
    end

structure BigInt : BIGINT = 
    struct
        type bigint = int list

        fun getbigint (i:int): bigint = [i];            
    end;
```

I cleaned up your implementation of `getbigint` since the `let` binding in it seemed a bit pointless, and chose something more idiomatic for names of the signature (all upper case) and structure (camel case with leading capital).

Finally, note that `getbigint 9` won't work out of the box. You can do one of three things:

1) Explicitly use the qualified name: `BigInt.getbigint 9`

2) Use the line `val getbigint = BigInt.getbigint` to give the name `getbigint` its intended meaning in the current scope

3) Use the line `open BigInt` to move the structure's definitions to the top-level, after which `getbigint 9` will work as expected.

When I started programming in SML, I used to open a lot of structures (`Char`, `List etc.). If you do this thoughtlessly, sooner or later you run into bugs where opening a structure introduces a name clash. For that reason, I now almost always use approach 1) or 2).